# How can I draw and fill up a table with while cycle?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I tried this way, but it isn't work.

```
$row2 = 0;  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo "<table border='1'>";
    if($row2 == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    elseif($row2 < 5){
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a href='movie.php'>";
        echo "<img class='movie' src='".$row['image']."' height='150' width='100'>";
        echo "</a>";
        echo $row['title'];
        echo "</td>";
        $sor++;
    }
    elseif($row2 == 5){
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo"</table>";
}
```

The while cycle is working, because if I print out just images, everything ok. The problem is only with the table.
I would like to draw a 5x2 table and fill it with movie posters and titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not increasing `$row2` (it looks like you are increasing `$sor`).

Also, place your `<table><tr>` / `</tr></table>` outside your loop.

You can also use modulus `%` so that if you increase the db rows it will increase your rows.

Try something like this (untested)

```
$row2 = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    if($row2%5== 0){
          echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='movie.php'>";
    echo "<img class='movie' src='".$row['image']."' height='150' width='100'>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "</td>";
    $row2++;
}
echo "</tr>";
echo"</table>";
```